# How can i manage response of navigator.credentials.get error?

Tags: credentials, webauthn, fido

I'm using `credentials.get` for get the cred stored on my browser. I have the list but i can't manage 2 case:

1- credentials are presented to the user in a modal dialog . If the user makes a gesture outside of the dialog, the dialog closes without resolving or rejecting the Promise and passe to the cache `DOMException: The operation either timed out or was not allowed.`
2- the user hasn't any cred stored and he click Ok. the dialog closes without resolving or rejecting the Promise and passe to the cache with `DOMException: The operation either timed out or was not allowed.`

How i can solve this?

Any help please

```
await navigator.credentials.get({ publicKey: options, }) .then((res) => { console.log(res) }).catch((err) => { console.log(err) })
```

Thanx

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am running into similar issues with public-key webauthn.